# How can I update existing mongodb database with a new array in Node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

My mongodb data is looking like this

```
[{"_id":"66076517c835e00d55714b41","UMKC":{"users":{"professors":[],"students":[],"admins":[]}}}]
,{"_id":"66076517c835e00d55714b41","UNT":{"users":{"professors":[],"students":[],"admins":[]}}}]]
```

I want to update the users accroding to their roles. The data needs to be appeneded looks like this

```
{
'fname':fname,
'lname':lname,
}
```

I tried updating it like this

```
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    const { fname, lname, email, univName, id, role, password, _id } = req.body;
    const adminData = { fname, lname, email, id, password }
    const filter = { _id: new ObjectId(_id) }
   
    try {
        const updateResult = await Users.updateOne({filter},
            {$push:{
                'users.admins':{
                    'fname':fname,
                    'lname':lname,
                    'id':id,
                    'email':email,
                    'password':password
                }
            }}
            );console.log(updateResult)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})
```

I followed a thread in [mongodb website](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/push-into-array-while-seting-fields-of-existing-elements/16527/4)

The Users model looks like this

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    fname: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        maxlength: 50
    },
    lname: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        maxlength: 50
    },

    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
            validator: (email) => /^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/.test(email),
            message: 'Please enter a valid email address.'
        }
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 8
    }
});

const Users = mongoose.model('Users', userSchema);

module.exports = Users; // Export the Users model directly
```

The data is not being updated in the db. Is there something I am doing wrong?

EDIT:

I tried changing the variable inside the push like this

```
'users.admins' to 'UNT.users.admins' also `[${univName].users.admins`
```

just to see if it works. But no luck

Comment: With the change `UNT.users.admins`, your code works fine. See [this working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KfdchkTZZf0). It's unclear from your question and the syntax of the data example if the two documents are separate or as part one one doc. If they are separate, the code is fine. Cannot reproduce the error you're describing. The only issue I see is that you're doing `filter = { _id: new ObjectId(_id) }` instead of just `filter = { _id: _id }` because the example has a string for `_id` fields and not `ObjectId`. Test your query with `findOne` to make sure the filter is correct.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply!! The change `UNT.users.admins` is not working. I tested the code if there is a document exists and accessing the data inside it. But it is returning undefined. I did it like this

`const existing = await Users.findById(_id); console.log(existing)`
this statement returns the document. But when I try to log the data inside it, its returing undefined `console.log(existing.UNT)` returns undefined

Edit: why is it returning undefined even though there is data inside that particular variable?